# I am trying to connect to postgres database instance in aws but I can't

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have the following code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var pg = require('pg');


var conString = "postgres://user:password@endpoint:5432/StudentRecords";

//this initializes a connection pool 
//it will keep idle connections open for a (configurable) 30 seconds 
//and set a limit of 20 (also configurable) 
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    client.connect(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
      }
      else{
        console.log("asdfaf")
      }
      });
client.connect();
```

It shows cannot connect to postgres. But when I try connecting from the terminal using

```
psql    --host=endpoint    --port=5432    --username xxxxx    --password   --dbname=StudentRecords
```

I can connect. Why is the code not working? Error I am getting is:

```
could not connect to postgres [Error: Connection terminated]
```

Comment: You cannot connect means which error message?

Comment: read your documentation for what "conString" is supposed to be.  In your psql you connect to a host called "endpoint".  The connection string seems to be trying to get to a host called "postgres"